# Adding http:// on form action doesn't return form input values

Tags: html, forms

Case 1:

```
<form action='update.php' method='post'>
```

Case 2:

```
<form action='http://site.net/update.php' method='post'>
```

Case 1 works fine, but when I add the full site URL including the http:// Case 2 returns an error. It doesn't give the values returned by the form.

Does using http:// or full URL prohibited?

Answer (score 0):

first one is relative.Second is specific.It is always better to use relative urls. not the specific urls